# How can I tell what version of mysqli is installed?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm putting together some documentation for developers and I want to include the required PHP extensions and versions of each. For instance, one requirement is gd 2.1.1 and another is phalcon 2.0.1.

I know how to figure out what versions of PHP and MySQL are installed, but I can't figure out what version of the mysqli extension I have. `phpinfo` shows the following information under the mysqli extension section:

```
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.5.43
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Client API header version   5.5.41
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I think this just tells me that the version of MySQL I have installed is 5.5.43, which I assume is different from the version of mysqli.

`dpkg` shows the version of php5-msyql is 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 (I think there's a .9 that's truncated), which I believe is the version of the metapackage and not necessarily the version of the extension:

```
$ dpkg -l php5-mysql
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-================================================================
ii  php5-mysql                    5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 amd64               MySQL module for php5
```

Comment: mysqli is just a PHP extension....

Comment: Yeah I know but other PHP extensions have version. For instance, GD is version 2.1.1, and Phalcon is 2.0.1. I'm trying to put together some documentation on the extensions developers need to install.

Comment: i assume you are aware the `phpInfo()` displays quite a lot of useful information about what PHP thinks it can use. It includes some version information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below:
http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionextension.getversion.php

```
$ext = new ReflectionExtension('mysqli');
var_dump($ext->getVersion());
// Output: string(3) "0.1"
```

Comment: So the version is 0.1? Is that even useful information to give another developer?

Comment: that output is just for demo. you will get what is installed in your machine. and sorry I didn't get your question. Can you please simplify that?

Comment: The output on my machine is 0.1. What I meant with my question was should I tell developers they need mysqli version 0.1 or is that implied?

Comment: Yes you can suggest to that that version of MySQLi to other developers.

Answer (score 0):

i found your answer just visit

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-server-version.php

put your database mysqli_connect link identifier without using database name

```
printf(mysqli_get_server_version($link));
```

Here  as o/p 50617        so our version is 5.6.7

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Comment: That function returns the version of MySQL server, not the version of the extension.

Comment: it display the version of mysqli version